# Physical Interpretation of Poynting Vector

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, poynting-vector

I'm looking for a physical interpretation of the Poynting Vector. I understand that it should be thought of as an energy flow due to the electromagnetic field, but would I be correct in saying that in some sense it's equivalent to a photon flow/packet? After all, for an electromagnetic wave, the poyntig vector yields the direction of propogation, or the direction in which the photon is moving. Does this analogy apply in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are basicaly right.

The Poynting vector gives you the momentum of the the EM wave. At the quantum level, it is an operator of the form (see page 7 of http://www.physics.usu.edu/torre/3700_Spring_2013/What_is_a_photon.pdf) :
$$\hat{\mathbf{P}}  =\sum_\mathbf{k} \mathbf{k}\, \hat a^\dagger_\mathbf{k} \hat a_\mathbf{k}$$
for a given polarisation (here $\hbar=1$).

This, if the system has just one photon with momentum $\mathbf{q}$, the average value $\mathbf{P}$ of the Poynting vector will be $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{q}$ has you would expect.